# How can I order by a custom function in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

So I have a SQLALchemy model as shown below

```
from sqlalchemy import (create_engine, Column, BigInteger, String, 
                        DateTime)
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

Base = declarative_base()

class Trades(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'trades'

    row_id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    order_id = Column(String)
    time = Column(DateTime)
    event_type = Column(String)

    @hybrid_property
    def event_type_to_integer(self):
        return dict(received=0, open=1, done=2)[self.event_type]

    @event_type_to_integer.expression
    def event_type_to_integer(self):
        pass
```

I want to be able to order a query first by the `time` then by `event_type`. Ordering by time is easy enough, since datetimes have a natural ordering. However ordering by `event_type` is a little tricky, since `event_type` can take the value `received`, `open`, and `done`. I want all of my queries to order queries by `event_type` in the above specified order. It seems I need to use hybrid properties, which I started to do above, but to get the `order_by` function to work it seems I also need to write the

```
    @event_type_to_integer.expression
    def event_type_to_integer(self):
        pass
```

function. This is where I'm drawing a blank. Does anyone have advice on how to write this function to do the above. I've tried reading the documentation and similar StackOverflow posts. Still having trouble. For reference. Here is the query I'm trying to get working

```
    sess = Session()

    orders = (
        sess
        .query(Trades)
        .order_by(Trades.time.asc(), Trades.event_type_to_integer.asc())
        .all()
        )

    sess.close()
```

It's throwing a

```
KeyError: <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x7fcb11861048>
```

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding but can't you just order by your `event_type` column in descending order since you want the values in reverse alphabetical order? In other words, is there some reason that `session.query(Trades).order_by(Trades.time.asc(), Trades.event_type.desc()).all()` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @benvc Yeah I suppose that is a solution. I would describe it as a little hacky, since it's exploiting a property that is coincidental rather than being representative of the underlying logic of the data. I was hoping to find something more robust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement your lookup with a [`CASE` expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) in SQL:

```
from sqlalchemy import case

_event_type_lookup = dict(received=0, open=1, done=2)

class Trades(Base):
    ...
    @hybrid_property
    def event_type_to_integer(self):
        return _event_type_lookup[self.event_type]

    @event_type_to_integer.expression
    def event_type_to_integer(cls):
        return case(_event_type_lookup, value=cls.event_type)
```

This uses the [`value`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case.params.value) shorthand of the [`case()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case) construct to produce an expression that compares the given column expression against the keys passed in the dictionary, yielding the mapped values as the result.