# using Levenshtein Distance to sort search query in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I've been trying to get Sqlalchemy to use a function ( Levenshtein Distance ) to order the results of a query , I've tried some of the ideas here and there , but none use a parameter that is not in the Sqlalchemy model it self , here is what i am trying to do :

```
    communs=baladiya.query.filter_by(wilaya=wilaya).filter(baladiya.name.like('%{}%'.format(name))).order_by(jf.Levenshtein_Distance(searchstring,baladiya.name)).paginate(per_page=4,page=page)
```

i am using this method to keep the app well structured and can use paginate object , 
if this is not possible at all  , is there a way to create an empty query , and then keep appending using my own sorting .

this is the baladiya model :

```
class baladiya(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer , primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.String(1000),unique=False , nullable=False)
postalcode = db.Column(db.String(10),unique=True, nullable=False)
posX = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=True, default='16000')
posY = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=True, default='16000')
wilaya= db.Column(db.Integer,unique=False, nullable=False)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53695927/how-can-i-order-by-a-custom-function-in-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 0):

i did some tries my self , and  what Sqlalchemy actually does when you pass a filter query , is that it creates a mysql based query  , which means it doesnt pull the data and applies the filter , but just send the request , you better pull the data you want , and then apply what ever  you want on that as a list    .