# How can I order by an upvotes function in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to order a Post query by time and how many upvotes it has received.

Here aremy Post class and Vote classes:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    id=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(140))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)

    votes = db.relationship('Vote', back_populates='facti', lazy='dynamic')

    def upvotes(self):
        return Vote.query.filter_by(facti_id=self.id, upvote=True).count()

    @hybrid_property
    def order_upvotes(self):
        return self.upvotes()

    @order_upvotes.expression
    def order_upvotes(cls):
        return cls.upvotes()

class Vote(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'vote'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    upvote = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

Here is the query I want to make with the order_by constructed

```
Post.query.order_by(Post.order_upvotes.desc(), Post.timestamp.desc())
```

Running it like this produces this error:

```
TypeError: upvotes() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I've tried using [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53695927/how-can-i-order-by-a-custom-function-in-sqlalchemy) But it doesn't seem I need a dictionary as my function only returns integers.

EDIT:
I changed the following:

```
    @order_upvotes.expression
    def order_upvotes(cls):
        return cls.upvotes()
```

to this:

```
    @order_upvotes.expression
    def order_upvotes(cls):
        return func.count(Vote.id).filter(Vote.id == cls.id, Vote.upvote==True)
```

Which seemed to work until I tried to query the results. It took my base query, but when I added all() to try and get the results it gave me issues with Voite.id which does exist in my class Vote. Any ideas?

```
>>> Post.query.order_by(Post.order_upvotes)
<flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery object at 0x7f3821e5a2e0>
>>> Post.query.order_by(Post.order_upvotes).all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jon/Post/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1276, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/home/jon/Post/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 609, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: vote.id

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jon/Post/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3373, in all
    return list(self)
  File "/home/jon/Post/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3535, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/home/jon/Post/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3560, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/home/jon/Post/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1011, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/jon/Post/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/jon/Post/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1124, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/home/jon/Post/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1316, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/home/jon/Post/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1510, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "/home/jon/Post/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/jon/Post/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1276, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/home/jon/Post/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 609, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: vote.id
[SQL: SELECT Post.id AS Post_id, Post.title AS Post_title, Post.body AS Post_body, Post.timestamp AS Post_timestamp, Post.language AS Post_language, Post.author_id AS Post_author_id, Post.saved_user_id AS Post_saved_user_id, Post.community_id AS Post_community_id, Post.parent_post_id AS Post_parent_post_id, Post.upPost_parent_id AS Post_upPost_parent_id, Post.downPost_parent_id AS Post_downPost_parent_id
FROM Post ORDER BY count(vote.id) FILTER (WHERE vote.id = Post.id AND vote.upvote = 1)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

I then changed it to:

```
    @order_upvotes.expression
    def order_upvotes(cls):
        return func.count(Vote)
```

This is the error I get with the query:

```
>>> Post.query.order_by(Post.order_upvotes.desc())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jon/Post/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/hybrid.py", line 898, in __get__
    return self._expr_comparator(owner)
  File "/home/jon/Post/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/hybrid.py", line 1105, in expr_comparator
    comparator(owner),
  File "/home/jon/Post/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/hybrid.py", line 1090, in _expr
    return ExprComparator(cls, expr(cls), self)
  File "/home/jon/Post/app/models.py", line 782, in order_upvotes
    return func.count(Vote)
  File "/home/jon/Post/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/functions.py", line 599, in __call__
    return func(*c, **o)
  File "/home/jon/Post/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/functions.py", line 906, in __init__
    super(count, self).__init__(expression, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jon/Post/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/functions.py", line 789, in __init__
    parsed_args = [_literal_as_binds(c, self.name) for c in args]
  File "/home/jon/Post/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/functions.py", line 789, in <listcomp>
    parsed_args = [_literal_as_binds(c, self.name) for c in args]
  File "/home/jon/Post/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 4815, in _literal_as_binds
    return BindParameter(name, element, type_=type_, unique=True)
  File "/home/jon/Post/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 1237, in __init__
    self.type = type_api._resolve_value_to_type(value)
  File "/home/jon/Post/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py", line 3045, in _resolve_value_to_type
    raise exc.ArgumentError(
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Object <class 'app.models.Vote'> is not legal as a SQL literal value
>>> Post.query.order_by(Post.order_upvotes.desc())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@order_upvotes.expression
    def order_upvotes(cls):
        return cls.upvotes()
```

should be

```
@order_upvotes.expression
    def order_upvotes(cls):
        return func.count(Vote.id).filter(Vote.id == cls.id, Vote.upvote=True)
```

Refer [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/hybrid.html) for more about hybrid expressions

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This worked until I tried to return the results with .all() in my query. It is saying there is no Vote.id in the schema which there is. Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure but just doing `func.count(Vote)` might be enough to get it to work

Comment: I tried that, but I got a different error
```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Object <class 'app.models.Vote'> is not legal as a SQL literal value
```

Any more ideas? I really appreciate your help.