# Sqlalchemy return column value with map func

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

```py
class MyClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type_id = Column(String(50))


# map value
type_name = {
    "type_id_1":"name_1",
    "type_id_2":"name_2"
}
```

Is there a way to return "type name" when doing query type_id from table Myclass ?

by using @hybrid_property, I got really close to the goal

```
class Myclass(Base):
    ...
    @hybrid_property
    def type_name(self):
        # The goal is get type_name, but it's not working since self.type_id is not a String object
        name = type_name[self.type_id] 
        return cast(name, String)
```

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/53700911/2681632 for how to use `case` to perform lookups SQL side.

Comment: @Ilja Everilä Awesome, this is exactly what I want, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

reading your question I interpreted it this way. Do you want this?

```
class MyClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type_id = Column(String(50))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<my_table(id='%s', type_id='%s')>" % (self.id, self.type_id)
```

Comment: Not exactly, what I need is : `return type_name[self.type_id]`